# Managing systemd services with Go

Tags: go

Outside of os.exec calling something, is there anything in the standard library for managing systemd services? I have seen a few 3rd party libraries that hook into dbus or integrate with systemd but I was trying to leverage the standard library as much as possible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard library but maybe this can be useful

```
https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd
```

I've tested it to just list all units.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/coreos/go-systemd/dbus"
)

func main() {

    systemdConnection, _ := dbus.NewSystemdConnection()

    listOfUnits, _ := systemdConnection.ListUnits()

    for _, unit := range listOfUnits {
        fmt.Println(unit.Name)
    }

    systemdConnection.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no systemd-specific API in standard library.